# Unity - 2D Moving platforms parenting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child, parent, unity3d-2dtools

I am struggling with a character parenting on moving platforms in 2D game.

I’m using OnTriggerEnter2D() for a detection when player steps on the moving platform. It changes his parent to that platform.
With common moving platforms (left-right) everything works fine, if a character stands on that platform he moves parallel with it, he can walk, jump etc.
The problem appears when I use the platform that hangs on two ropes connected with HingeJoint2Ds.
The player should swing that platform by walking left and right.
When using a keyboard input everything works fine but with a touch-input controller, when player doesn't move, the character remains on one place and doesn’t move with that platform. In a hierarchy panel is everything correct, player is a child of platform and the platform is moving but character isn't.

For moving character I’m using this: (part of character controller)

```
float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal”);
rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);
```

That’s the same for keyboard and touch input. Difference is only in the “move” variable getting.
The solution for moving and swinging platforms is same too. (hierarchy, parents, colliders etc.)

I am struggling with this for several hours but I have no idea what could be wrong.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you call a "touch input controller", is it a touch device? If so, are you sure `Input.GetAxis("Horizontal”)` does anything on touch devices? won't it just return 0 always?

Have you tried logging your `move` value, or copying it to a public variable to watch it evolve in the inspector? Maybe the values are orders of magnitude apart between one controller and the other, in which case you would need a multiplier.

Comment: "Touch input controller" is a part of my character controller used for mobile devices. In that case I don't use "Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), I simply set the "move" value to 1 or -1 when player pushes a walk button. And that was the bug. I set 0 for move when the walk button was not pressed. That's why the character was not moving even when stands on moving platform. I solved it adding a 'platform.rigidbody2D.velocity' to the 'character.velocity'. Now it works fine. Really helped logging 'move' value. Thanks